# What type of ailerons does the Piper Seminole has?

Tags: aircraft-performance, flight-controls

I understand that the PA44 has differential type ailerons, but do they also have frise type ailerons? Making them a combination of differential and frise type similar to the Cessna 150/152/172 models?

Thank you!